# MySQL: Invoke trigger after transaction is committed

Tags: mysql, transactions, triggers

I've a very simple database with following schema:

```
video (id, title, description)
category (id, name)
tag (id, name)

video_category_reference (video_id, category_id)
video_tag_reference(video_id, tag_id)

abc_table (video_id, description, categories)
```

The first five tables use InnoDB engine.

The last table - `abc_table` uses MyISAM engine and it contains some kind of "cache". `description` column stores the result of `CONCAT(video.title, video.description, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name))` and `categories` column stores the result of `GROUP_CONCAT(category.id)`.

What I need is a trigger that will populate `abc_table` after a new video is created. A new video will be created always the same way:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO video VALUES(NULL, "My video", "description");

SET @vid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO video_category_reference VALUES (@vid, 1), (@vid, 2), (@vid, 3), (@vid, 4);
INSERT INTO video_tag_reference VALUES (@vid, 5), (@vid, 6), (@vid, 7), (@vid, 8);

COMMIT;
```

Unfortunately I can't use this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_on_video AFTER INSERT ON video FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @categories = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category_id) FROM video_category_reference WHERE video_id = NEW.id GROUP BY video_id);
    SET @tags = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) FROM video_tag_reference vtr JOIN tag t ON vtr.tag_id = t.id WHERE video_id = NEW.id GROUP BY video_id);

    INSERT INTO video_search_table VALUES (NEW.id, CONCAT(NEW.title, NEW.raw_description, @tags), @categories);
END$$
```

...as it will be executed before inserts on `*_reference` tables will be done.

---

Is there any way I could force MySQL to execute a trigger after the transaction is commited? Or do I have to create triggers for `*_referemce` tables that will modify values in `abc_table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your trigger to AFTER UPDATE and have a quick:

```
UPDATE video SET id=@vid WHERE id=@vid;
```

to trigger the trigger before the transaction ends.  Bonus: if your video information is updated, the trigger runs again =D.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are used precisely because they occur within the transaction: if an error occurs in a trigger, the entire transaction rolls back, no messy orphans or partial data.

So the best thing is to rework the tables so that (hopefully) a single trigger on one table will do the trick.