# MySql: Enforce creation of child-table entries

Tags: mysql

In my database structure I've come across the following issue.

```
   cable table
----------------------------
| id | description | type_id |
----------------------------

   cableEnd table
------------------------
| cabel_id | address_id | 
------------------------
```

The parent table *cable* contains general information and the child table *cableEnd* contains location specific information. For a cable to be valid it must have at least two ends. My issue is that I wish to ensure that these are created, as it is possible that someone creates a cable entry but forget to create leading to invalid/uncompleted data.

I could automatically create the two entries via a trigger on insertion to the cable entry. However as address information would not be provided, these entries would be as useless as no entries.

In my scripts I can easily ensure both tables are filled though transactions such as.

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO cable(description, type_id) VALUES('Lorem ipsum', 1);
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO cableEnd(@id, '123');
INSERT INTO cableEnd(@id, '345');
COMMIT;
```

[insert data to parent and child table at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215555/insert-data-to-parent-and-child-table-at-the-same-time). To the topic are many one of the many related questions.

However I cannot know with certainty that values have not been inserted manually via phpMyadmin or whatever. 
Worst case scenario I can periodically query the database to find any cable entries that do not have ends, but this does not seem like an ideal solution.
I had hoped that I could somehow simultaneously insert into the two tables allowing for an AFTER_INSERT trigger to confirm validity. Or to somehow call the same trigger after the transaction and a manual insertion. This does not seem to be possible. [MySQL: Invoke trigger after transaction is committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972292/mysql-invoke-trigger-after-transaction-is-committed)

After a good couple of days I’m still no closer to a solution, yet doubt that I’m the first to have this sort of issue.
Any suggestions to how I can solve this situation without merging the two tables would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try to revoke `INSERT` on `cable` and instead write a procedure that has to be used to `INSERT` into `cable`. That procedure needs data for the ends as well and creates the three needed records. What is the maximum number of ends a cable can have?

Comment: One solution could be to fix your database design. You have a 1-1 relationship between a cable, its first end and its second end. Why not just store all three information in the same table record ?

Comment: @stickybit This would not solve the situation where an entry would be manually be added. A cable must always have two ends.

Comment: @Ish: When the `INSERT` right is revoked from the table a "manual" adding of a cable -- I believe you mean `INSERT INTO cable` issued by a user with that term, cannot be done anymore.

Comment: @GMB You may very well be right in your critic, however I am trying to avoid this. 
It greatly increases the size of the cable tabel with two of every cableEnd field, and cause a lot of complexity in the scripts that track the cables and services that are running on the cables.

Comment: @stickybit Ah sorry I overlooked the suggestion to revoke the INSERT permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stored Procedures as an alternate instead of triggers with parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateCable(_description varchar(50), _type_id int, _address1 int, _address2 int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE InsertID INT;
    START TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO cable(description, type_id) VALUES(_description, _type_id);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO InsertID;
    INSERT INTO cableEnd(cabel_id, address_id) VALUES (InsertID, _address1);
    INSERT INTO cableEnd(cabel_id, address_id) VALUES (InsertID, _address2);
    COMMIT;
END
```

And call the stored procedure using

```
CALL CreateCable('Lorem Ipsum', 1, 123, 345)
```

So it fulfill your requirement